# Android - Get same intent from different activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i'm currently working with three activities: mainActivity, readActivity, and searchActivity.

I'd like readActivity to get an Intent (a String with a SQLite query) from any of the two other activities.But until now, I've worked with activities this way:

In the current activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ReadActivity.class);
String query = "SQLITE QUERY";
Intent.putExtra(intent_extra, query);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the next activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String query = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.intent_extra);
```

Is there a way to read a default intent without naming the activity from where it comes from? A quick way to check the last activity would work as well!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the String, that is used as the key for accessing the EXTRA is defined.

You can specify the EXTRA-keys as Strings in a resource file and access them via the receiving activity:

**Resource file `strings.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="extra_sql_query">extra.SqlQuery</string>
</resources>
```

**Receiver**

```
getIntent();
String query = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.extra_sql_query);
```

**Caller**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ReadActivity.class);
String query = "SQLITE QUERY";
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.extra_sql_query, query);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

**However if there is only one activity...**

handling those intents it would be better to save the EXTRA-keys in the receiving Activity.

**Receiver**

```
public class ReadActivity extends Activity {
     public final static String EXTRA_SQL_QUERY = "sql.query";
```

and

```
getIntent();
String query = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SQL_QUERY);
```

**Caller**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ReadActivity.class);
String query = "SQLITE QUERY";
intent.putExtra(ReadActivity.EXTRA_SQL_QUERY, query);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know about the EXTRA resource! Although I didn't use it this time, I'm sure it will be useful. The second answer worked fine!

Comment: I am sorry. I seem to have been too tired to answer correctly. There is no EXTRA-resource. It is just a xml-resource-file where you can place for example string-definitions. You can also name the file foobar.xml or store the values in the commonly used strings.xml. Probably strings.xml is the best place for it, as all string-resources share the same namespace. I just corrected my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this, although 1 problem is

```
    Intent.putExtra(intent_extra, query);
```

Should be

```
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.intent_extra, query);
```

because you have to add it to your variable for the intent, not the android class, wherever you want your query string passed to an activity. Then to retrieve it, call it by

```
intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.intent_extra);
```

as you already are.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

first, change

```
Intent.putExtra(intent_extra, query);
```

`intent_extra` to any value. ex.

```
Intent.putExtra("the_query", query);
```

then recieve it by its name.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String query = intent.getStringExtra("the_query");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ReadActivity.class);
String query = "SQLITE QUERY";
Intent.putExtra(MainActivity.intent_extra, query);
startActivity(intent);
```

It's exactly the same almost from any other activity.  See above grab the constant intent_extra ( which by the way should be capitalized) from the MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

you can use bundles, so in the receiving activity you invoke getIntent().getBundle() and you don't care where it came from