# Delete a pending alarm / notification from service

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an activity that calls a Helper, where I create a notification what will pop-up in a selected time. It works great.

I want to create another function in a different activity that can delete a pending alarm before the notification pops up. I tried many ways I found online but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Add Alarm
public class Helper {
    public void SetAlarm(Activity activity, int requestCode, Calendar calendar, String title, ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemintent(Context.ALARM_intent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("title",title);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, requestCode, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
    }
}


// Delete Alarm
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog progress;
    // ...
    public void Delete(int requestCode , String title) {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, getString(R.string.title), getString(R.string.text), true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                // .... 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);
                            intent.putExtra("title",title); // don't know if really needed
                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemintent(Context.ALARM_intent);
                            PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.cancel(pi);
                            // Tried that also - didn't work:
                            // PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
                            // pi.cancel();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            // ...
                        }
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                });
              }
        }).start();
    }
}





// BroadcastReceiver
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       newIntent.putExtra("title",  intent.getExtras().getString("title"));
       context.startService(newIntent);  
    }   
}

public class MyAlarmService extends Service 
{
    // ...

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY, startId);

        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
           .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
           .setContentText(getString(R.string.conText))
           .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
           .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
           .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        mManager.notify(0, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the same `Intent` when you cancel your `PendingIntent`.

Comment: It's a total different activity. How can I use the same intent?  can't I just recreate it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593442/android-get-same-intent-from-different-activities

Comment: The intent that I create to set the alarm can be created weeks before I try to call it again to delete the alarm.

Comment: Do you want to cancel the alarms gonna trigger in future? Or want to delete triggered in past?

Comment: I want to cancel alarms in the future.

Comment: The cancelling intent has to match the original (action, data, type, class, and categories are the same). Have you tried to call PendingIntent.getBroadcast() without the flags? (0 instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT). And make sure you are using the same request code.

Comment: @dev.bmax -  
Oh no. I really used the wrong function to get the requestCode and then I get a different number. I was so sure it's the right one I didn't even check... I checked now only because you asked. You can post you comment as an answer and I'll give you 50 points!

Comment: I'm glad it has worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cancelling intent has to match the original (action, data, type, class, and categories are the same). Have you tried to call PendingIntent.getBroadcast() without the flags? (0 instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT). And make sure you are using the same request code.

Comment: Indeed - I wrongly used a wrong requestCode and I haven't notice!

Answer (score 0):

Create your alarm like this:

```
public static void createAlarm(Context context, Calendar calAlarm, String ALARM_ACTION_NAME)
{
    try
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Create an alarm intent
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION_NAME);

        // Create the corresponding PendingIntent object
        PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        // cancel any alarms previously set
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmPI);

        // Register the alarm with the alarm manager
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), alarmPI);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And you can cancel it like this:

```
public static void cancelAlarm(Context context, String ALARM_ACTION_NAME)
{
    try
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Create an alarm intent
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION_NAME);

        // Create the corresponding PendingIntent object
        PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        // cancel any alarms previously set
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmPI);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ALARM_ACTION_NAME ?

Comment: Where do you use MyReciever? Where do you create the notification?